# How can one get VirtualBox installed and working on Amazon Linux 2 AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualbox, docker-swarm, docker-machine

at the download page https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

I noted

> Users of Fedora can add  the Fedora repo file to /etc/yum.repos.d/.

So I created a file virtualbox.repo at `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and pasted in

```
[virtualbox]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - VirtualBox
baseurl=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc
```

Then I did

`yum-config-manager --enable virtualbox.repo`

and the output was:

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd

So I thought it might have worked.

But when I run

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1`

I get

```
Running pre-create checks...

Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. 
Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

I am trying to follow along the Docker get started tutorial here https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/

But I am stuck, unable to get VirtualBox to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try 'yum install virtualbox' after setting up the repo and before attmepting the 'docker-machine' command?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak No, I hadn't thank you. I tried it now and got the following: pastebin.com/raw/4DvHWDXB ... I then tried running yum --disablerepo=virtualbox install virtualbox and got the following output: pastebin.com/raw/iNDp5BCr ... Any ideas? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't believe you can run Virtualbox on EC2. If all you want to do is run Docker then you can launch EC2 and install Docker, or you can use ECS.

Comment: The reason to use VirtualBox is to create virtual machines  _on your local computer_ that you can then manage with `docker machine`. Read [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started-cloud/) to learn how to run `docker machine` on a cloud provider.

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks I will have a read.

Comment: jarmod is, of course, correct.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Also, once you've created a VirtualBox VM on your local machine, AWS will support importing (and exporting) VirtualBox VMs into an AMI (or out of an AMI).